# Intel App Framework or Bootstrap for Intel XDK?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, intel

I am looking at using the Intel XDK to develop a mobile application.

Should I use Intel's App framework, which might work better with XDK, or Twitter's Bootstrap?  I am familiar with Bootstrap but am not sure how well it will integrate with XDK.

**Do you have any recommendations/suggestions as to which will work better?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel App Framework will give you more native app like look and feel. It is mainly meant for developing apps. It is light weight and very fast. It has native style UI themes for iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8 and Blackberry10 that is automatically applied based on the device type.

Bootstrap is more comprehensive responsive web framework that can be used to develop website or mobile web app. The UI may not look and feel like native app, but is a good option if you want to reuse the code for mobile and desktop website.

Both integrate well with Intel XDK.

Comment: When I loaded a sample app onto my iPad, (just a demo app), it didn't seem to change to an iOS theme. Is it something that just hapens when you actually build and deploy it?

Comment: depends on which version of appframework you are using, try these samples: https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates